# Decompiled NewLateBinding Value

Tags: c#, decompiler

I have an old application that lost it's original source code and ran into an issue with a NewLateBinding.LateGet and seeing where a variable comes from. I checked the documentation and it says `Executes a late-bound property get or field access call. This helper method is not meant to be called directly from your code.` This is the line of code I'm seeing.

```cs
NewLateBinding.LateGet((object) model, (Type) null, "Precision", new object[0], (string[]) null, (Type[]) null, (bool[]) null)
```

The documentation says the field `Precision` is:

```
MemberName
String
The name of the property or method on the call object.
```

The confusing part is that the class doesn't have a property, or method called `Precision`. Where else could this value be coming from? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

This is how it's being used.

```cs
num2 = Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet((object) model, (Type) null, "Precision", new object[0], (string[]) null, (Type[]) null, (bool[]) null));

num3 = Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet((object) model, (Type) null, "Scale", new object[0], (string[]) null, (Type[]) null, (bool[]) null));
```

Comment: All properties and classes have a built in header that is used for error checking and to get type.  The Precision is part of the header.

Comment: Is there also a variable called Scale in the header? The late binding is used in 2 places.


num2 = Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet((object) model, (Type) null, "Precision", new object[0], (string[]) null, (Type[]) null, (bool[]) null));
                
num3 = Conversions.ToInteger(NewLateBinding.LateGet((object) model, (Type) null, "Scale", new object[0], (string[]) null, (Type[]) null, (bool[]) null));

Comment: See following : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Odbc/OdbcDataReader.cs,289882e2dbb9fa6c

Comment: @jdweng That would explain the Precision and Scale field. Is there a reference guide on how to get those values without the LateBinding? They're the only fields I'm missing from my model that I need to store in the database, but I'm not sure how they should be accessed since I'm reverse engineering the code.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/august/net-reflection-dynamically-bind-your-data-layer-to-stored-procedures-and-sql-commands-using-net-metadata-and-reflection